# Spring Webflow: The field type is required

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tags, spring-webflow

I have been struggling with the following error for a while.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field type is required
```

I have a basic screen flow set up with 3 screens.

- Screen 1: identity
- Screen 2: contact information
- Screen 3: summary

From screen 1 I take in text fields as such:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="booking" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" method="post">
     User Name: 
     <form:input type="text" id="username" name="username" path="username"/>
     <input type="submit" name="_eventId_next" value="next" />
     <input type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form:form>
```

This works when it hits the summary, because I am able to display the content of ${booking.username} on the summary screen.

But on screen 2 when I try the exact same thing but with a different datafield an error that is specified above.

screen 2:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="booking" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" method="post">
     Address 1:
     <form:input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" path="address1"/>
     <input type="submit" name="_eventId_next" value="Next"/>
     <input type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel"/>
</form:form>
```

form tag specified as such:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Most of the code can be viewed on my previous question:

[Full Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630546/sharing-object-across-screens-using-spring-webflow)

The same error happens when I try to add form tags to a option drop box field as such.

```
<form:select id="requestType" name="requestType" path="requestType">
    <form:option value="0"></option> 
    <form:option value="1">Oprion 1</option>
    <form:option value="2">Option 2</option>
</form:select>
```

Instead of option tag I also tried

```
<form:input type="text" label="" value="0"/>
```

all come up with the same error pointing to these lines as an error.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Stack trace:
exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'enterContactDetails' of flow 'flow-config'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'enterContactDetails' of flow 'flow-config'
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:571)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:262)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'account/BookingContactDetailsScreen'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/account/BookingContactDetailsScreen.jsp]
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:191)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field type is required
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:50)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field type is required
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.<init>(ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel.findSpringConvertingPropertyEditor(BindingModel.java:277)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel.getFormattedValue(BindingModel.java:235)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel.getFieldValue(BindingModel.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.account.BookingContactDetailsScreen_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(BookingContactDetailsScreen_jsp.java:230)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.account.BookingContactDetailsScreen_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(BookingContactDetailsScreen_jsp.java:127)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.account.BookingContactDetailsScreen_jsp._jspService(BookingContactDetailsScreen_jsp.java:85)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:50)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: can you post stacktrace.

Comment: I've added as you requested

Comment: I doubt this is messing it up, but do you realize you don't need `action="${flowExecutionUrl}"` or `method="post"` in your `form:form`? Also, the `name` attribute on the `input` fields isn't normal either. I wonder if that could be confusing it. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#spring-form.tld.input

Comment: I started adding anything I could think of trying to fix this error. So if there are unnecessary fields, that is probably why. The clean version without the things you specified creates the same error, so sadly that is not the problem.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't define a type on your fields.  The type is determined by the tag, such that <form:input> is type="text", <form:hidden> is type="hidden", etc.  This may be confusing it as well.

Comment: Also, I think your taglib import needs to be <%@ taglib prefix="spring"  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

Comment: Hi, I don't think it is http://www.springframework.org/tags, the form tag is unrecognized then. Also as I said above, I have tried with all possible tags starting from the most plane possible <form:input path="address1"/>, the error still report saying a type needs to be specified.

Comment: I might end up abandoning webflow and just using MVC. I thought it would be easier to do the task I want, but it is just proving to be a hassle and seems to be less support online for it. Thank you all for attempting to help! I will keep a copy of my code in case anyone will ever think of something so I can test it out!

Comment: what is your model `booking` looks like? what are the properties in the model?

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to provide form action. You should have your form opening tag look like sample below:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="booking">
```