# Can't access bean properties of model object across Spring webflow views

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I've looked through numerous articles and posts on stack overflow, but can't seem to find my solution to this (including this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630546/sharing-object-across-screens-using-spring-webflow)).  I'm new to Spring (and webflow) but not to Java.

I have form pages using Spring Webflow 2.3.2, the input data for which I simply want to persist using Hibernate3 to MySQL5.  The problem is, I don't see values from the model (rentalApplication) persisting between pages.  I will post the relevant code but if there's more detail needed, I can update accordingly.

**flow.xml:**

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

  <on-start>
    <evaluate expression="rentalApplicationController.newForm()" result="flowScope.rentalApplication" />
  </on-start>

  <view-state id="rentalapp1" view="embeddedFlow/rentalapp1" model="rentalApplication">
    <transition on="next" to="rentalapp2">
      <evaluate
      expression="rentalApplicationController.update(rentalApplication)"
      result="flowScope.rentalApplication"/>
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" bind="false" history="discard"/>
    <transition on="save" to="save">
      <evaluate
      expression="rentalApplicationController.update(rentalApplication)"
      result="flowScope.rentalApplication"/>
    </transition>
  </view-state>

  <view-state id="rentalapp2" view="embeddedFlow/rentalapp2" model="rentalApplication">
    <transition on="previous" to="rentalapp1" validate="false"/>
    <transition on="next" to="rentalapp3">
      <evaluate
      expression="rentalApplicationController.update(rentalApplication)"
      result="flowScope.rentalApplication"/>
     </transition>
    <transition on="save" to="save">
      <evaluate
      expression="rentalApplicationController.update(rentalApplication)"
      result="flowScope.rentalApplication"/>
    </transition>
```

...

**Controller:**

```
@Service(value="rentalApplicationController")
public class RentalApplicationController extends FormAction {

    public RentalApplication newForm() {
    return rentalApplicationDao.create();
    }

    public RentalApplication update(RentalApplication rentalApp) {
    rentalApplicationDao.update(rentalApp);

    //not the best way to do this, but making sure we get
    //the updated data from the db
    int id = rentalApp.getId();
    return rentalApplicationDao.retrieve(id);
    }
}
```

**Config:**

```
  <bean id="formAction"
    class="com.foo.bar.RentalApplicationController">
  </bean>
  <bean id="primaryApplicant"
    class="com.foo.bar.account.Applicant"
    scope="session">
  </bean>
  <bean id="coApplicant"
    class="com.foo.bar.account.Applicant"
    scope="session">
  </bean>
  <bean id="rentalApplication"
    class="com.foo.bar.property.RentalApplication"
    scope="session">
  </bean>
<bean name="formAction" class="com.foo.bar.RentalApplicationController">
    <property name="formObjectName"><value>rentalApplication</value></property>
    <property name="formObjectClass"><value>com.foo.bar.RentalApplication</value>     </property>
    <property name="validator">
      <bean class="com.foo.bar.RentalApplicationValidator"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**DAO implementation:**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@Service("rentalApplicationService")

public class RentalApplicationDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements RentalApplicationDao {

    public RentalApplication create() {
    return new RentalApplication();
    }

    public void update(RentalApplication rentalApplication) {
        this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(rentalApplication);
    }

    public RentalApplication retrieve(int id) {
        return (RentalApplication)   getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(RentalApplication.class, id);
    }
```

**POJOS:**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="RENTAL_APPLICATION")
public class RentalApplication implements Serializable {

    public RentalApplication() {
       this.setDateCreated(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
       this.setPrimaryApplicant(new Applicant());
       this.setCoApplicant(new Applicant());
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("APPLICANT")
public class Applicant implements Serializable {
    //getters and setters including the one for email
}
```

**rentalapp1 JSP:**

```
<form:form id="rentalapp1" commandName="rentalApplication" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" method="POST">
<form:input path="primaryApplicant.email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Primary Applicant Email" data-type="email"/><br/>
</form:form>
```

**rentalapp2 JSP:**

```
Date Created: <c:out value="${rentalApplication.dateCreated}"></c:out><br/>  <!--PRINTS DATE-->
Primary ID: <c:out value="${rentalApplication.primaryApplicant.id}"></c:out><br/> <!--PRINTS 0-->
Primary email: <c:out value="${rentalApplication.primaryApplicant.email}"></c:out><br/> <!--PRINTS EMPTY STRING EVEN IF SUPPLIED -->
```

The SQL output using log4jdbc shows that the inserts are happening.  Perhaps the error is in the flow.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the flowScope bean in evaluate expression as:

```
    <evaluate expression="rentalApplicationController.update(flowScope.rentalApplication)"
        result="flowScope.rentalApplication"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Was able to solve this with a bit of re-work.  Will post when I get a free moment.

Comment: Giving you the check mark.  Thanks for the help on this!